# python float formatting weirdness?

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

I'm trying to debug two different python scripts that execute very similar code.  These scripts set    `a`, which is a simple float.

For script 1:

```
ipdb> print sys.version
2.7 (r27:82500, Jul 15 2010, 13:04:38)
[GCC 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)]
ipdb> type(a)
<type 'float'>
ipdb> print a
17.23105
ipdb> print '{0:.4f}'.format(a)
17.2311
```

For script 2:

```
ipdb> print sys.version
2.7 (r27:82500, Jul 15 2010, 13:04:38)
ipdb> print type(a)
<type 'float'>
ipdb> print a
17.23105
ipdb> print '{0:.4f}'.format(a)
17.2310
```

How is it possible that `a` formats differently in the two cases?  In what ways can `a` possibly differ between the two scripts, if I've already checked that their value is the same at `17.23105` ?  (unfortunately the python code that originally sets `a` is very, very long... I wouldn't want to bore everyone with 1000+ lines)

Comment: Are initiallizing `a` with the same value each time?  You haven't shown us how `a` gets created.  The reason I ask is that I want to know if it is possible that they were created with slightly different inputs.

Comment: `a` is certainly created a little differently in the two scripts.  My apologies for not posting code, but it really is too long to post :(    I was hoping that this debugging information is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `str` representation of a float truncates to 12 digits on Python 2. This is unfortunate. You have to `print repr(a)` to make sure you see enough precision to uniquely identify the float. There's probably a tiny difference that only shows up after 12 digits.

On Python 3, `str` and `repr` produce the same output for floats, so you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: wow, yeah... this is the case.  Script 1 has `repr(a)` as `17.231050000000003` , while Script 2 has `repr(a)` as `17.23105`.  It is a little strange that these two representations format differently as `{0:.4f}`.

Comment: Yup. The first one is big enough to round up; the second one is small enough to round down. (Note that since floating-point uses binary, both of those numbers technically have a huge trail of digits on the end that you're not seeing; you can `import decimal` and `print decimal.Decimal(a)` to see the exact values Python is using to approximate `17.23105` and `17.231050000000003`.)

Comment: thanks.  I guess one has to be really, really careful with floating point operations :)